# ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name using ORACLE

Tags: oracle

With my below debugged query, I got error as

> ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

Here is the query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey,
  vehicle_no,
  TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
  || ' & '
  || time_in vehicleindate_time,
  TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
  || ' & '
  || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
  gate_no_in
  || ' & '
  || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
  gd.good_type goods_type,
  net_weight netweight,
  TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
  || ' & '
  || challan_no challandate_no,
  remark_in remarkin,
  NULL receipt_no,
  date_in
FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv,
  xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd,
  xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms
WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+)         = sv.good_type)
AND ( sv.project_id                 = DECODE(:'  1368','0', project_id, :'1368')
AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = DECODE(:'  ', '0', date_in, :'  ')
AND vehicle_no                      = DECODE(:'  GJ-06-0Z-9202', '0', vehicle_no, :'  GJ-06-0Z-9202') )) 
AND sv.delete_flag = 'N' 
ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no
```

I am using `ORACLE`. I don't know what's the error. I am not much into i. Kindly suggest.

**UPDATE**

my code of query

```
strquerry = "SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no, TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' & ' || time_in vehicleindate_time, TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy') || ' & ' " +
                 "|| time_out vehicleoutdate_time, gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno, gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight, TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy') " +
                 "|| ' & ' || challan_no challandate_no,remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv, xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd, " +
                 "xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type) AND ( " +
                 "sv.project_id = DECODE(:'" + cmbProjectName.SelectedValue + "', 0, project_id, :'" + cmbProjectName.SelectedValue + "') " +
                 "AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = DECODE(:'" + txtdatefilter.Text + " ', '0', date_in, :'" + txtdatefilter.Text + "') " +
                 "AND vehicle_no = DECODE(:'" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "', 0, vehicle_no, :'" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "') " +
                 ")) AND sv.delete_flag = 'N' ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no";
```